# Completely locked out of MySQL!

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I've somehow managed to completely lock myself out of MySQL on WAMP. It seems all privileges are denied for all users. The only way I can get into MySQL is via the command prompt but without entering a user. From there, I quite literally cannot do anything... all privileges are denied. I've tried updating the root password to no avail.

I've also tried completely uninstalling WAMP as well as MySQL. After uninstalling MySQL, I deleted the data directories inside them to get rid of all the info there. After re-installing WAMP, the problem persists.

Attempts to access PHPMyAdmin results in:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Can anyone help??

**EDIT** Why are people voting to close this post...?

**EDIT2** A wild [secondary problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387712/wamp-re-install-causes-error-could-not-execute-the-service-has-not-been-start) appears! What do you want to do? Answer or navigate away?

Comment: Starting the mysql server with the `--skip-grant-tables` command line option bypasses the user/password authentication, letting you go in with superuser privileges, at which point you can reset the root account's password.

Comment: @Marc okay, so what exactly do I type in to run it with this option? I tried `mysql --skip-grant-tables` which results in `unknown option` so I assume I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: The option applies to the mysql SERVER, not the command line client. It'd probably be mysqld.exe (note the D). or something similar. You'd probably have to shut down the server first before you can re-run it manually.

Comment: @Marc I'm not sure if I interpreted your response correctly, but I tried `mysqld --skip-grant-tables` and the command line sits there unresponsive but does not give me an error message.

Comment: I've never used mysql on windows, but possibly the server's running at that point, so do that command, then open another shell and try going into the client (mysql.exe, no D) and try your grant queries.

Comment: @Marc Not sure if this is relevant, but I tried going into the services tab of Windows Task Manager. Attempts to stop `wampmysqld` results in an error: `Access is denied`

Comment: You'd need to be doing that with adminsitrator privileges. If you can't get that, and/or the wamp stuff can't shut down mysql for you, then try booting in safe mode.

Comment: @Marc I was able to stop mysql from wamp... Tried the grant queries with `mysqld --skip-grant-tables` running in another command line... same `access denied` errors.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try putting the `skip-grant-tables` into the `[mysqld]` section of the my.cnf/my.ini (and then restart the server), but you'd have to go remove it again afterwards to restore the regular permissions system.

Comment: @Marc Another good suggestion, but I've already followed the guide [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) that a few people have linked to... this also does not work.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. skip-grant-tables is the only way to get into mysql after you've gotten locked out completely.

Comment: Check that the database files themselves (not just the mysql-specific exe's/libraries) are being removed. Those may be preserved after an uninstall and then you're back to square one with the original 'bad' database. No idea WAMP keeps them, but you could look for `*.frm` files.

Comment: @Michael Yeah I posted the same thing there as well, got almost identical responses to those here. @Marc When I removed MySQL I removed the `Data` folders, does that count?

Comment: @Michael @Marc So what do I do now? Do I have any options left?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to reset the root password using `mysqladmin` from the command line.

```
mysqladmin password your-new-root-password
```

Might need to specify the root user explicitly:

```
mysqladmin -u root password your-new-root-password
```

Might also help to flush privileges from `mysqladmin`:

```
mysqladmin flush-privileges
```

Then you might need to grant all privileges back to root.  Not sure if this is necessary.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'your-new-password';
```

Comment: @Michael people keep giving me commands like this... I always get that they are "not recognized as an internal or external command". These are for the windows command line, right?

Comment: @Tory on Windows, you might need to specify the full path to mysqladmin.  Maybe it's something like `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.x\bin\mysqladmin`?  You'll need to find where it's installed on your system.

Comment: @Michael Tried this, `Access denied: You need the SUPER privilege for this operation`

Comment: @Tory Try specifying the root user on the command line. See edit above.

Comment: @Michael Tried the second command with `-u root`: `error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. I also tried the third command. `Access denied; you need the RELOAD privilege for this operation'`

Comment: @Tory are you logged in as an administrator on the Windows machine? If it's a regular user account you probably can't do any of this.

Comment: @Michael Yes, I am logged in on the only account on the machine which is the administrator account.

Comment: doesn't work for me on linux--maybe answer is dated now.  this did: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/ or this too: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Does not work.. `PS > ./mysqladmin -u root password newPW`
`mysqladmin.exe: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server'`

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Make sure that the mysqld process is killed before you try to do the reset. Try logging into the mysql client as you say yuo can in your question.

Comment: You're the third person to link to that page... I believe whatever admin is supervising this page has removed them all. Either way, I've attempted exactly that.

Comment: it's not admins - it's the people posting the answers deleting them themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If a complete wipe and reinstall results in the same problem, it's likely that there is an issue in your environment that's the problem.

You don't mention what version of Windows you're using, but I'm assuming that it's Vista or higher with those daft user privilege issues.  I would check to make sure that the mysql service user account has read/write access to the mysql data directories & files.

**REQUESTED ELABORATION:**

To check the account a service is running under, open services.msc, scroll down the appropriate service, and look at the column "Log On As" (or double click the service and then click on the "Log On" tab).

To check the permissions of the MySQL data files and folders, right click on the parent folder and select "Properties", then the "Security" tab (I'm not sure if you'll have a Security tab with Home, though - you wouldn't in XP).

If the account the service runs under doesn't have full control of the folder and the files in it, you'll need to edit the permissions to add that user (or change the user the service runs under).

If all that doesn't point you in the right direction, you should look for detailed instructions for installing WAMP on Win7 Home and make sure you follow them to the letter, as permissions and so forth are rather a PITA on Win7.  It may even be that Win7 Home won't let you run a webserver/sql server as a service, as the home versions of Windows are often deliberately crippled like that (fr'instance, you can't run IIS on WinXP Home, and folder security permissions are hidden).

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 32-bit Home. Could you elaborate on the last part of your response? I'm not sure how to go about doing so.

Comment: Added more detail for you in my original post.

Comment: Regarding Michael's comments about the admin account: on Win XP and above Home versions there is a hidden Admin account that you cannot access unless you boot into safe mode, but is used by the system.  This is where the "Run as admin" option comes from when you right click on something. You may need to run the WAMP installer this way for it to properly install - check the WAMP docs thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to re-gain access just by running mysql_secure_installation from the command line.  It ran me thru some y/n questions and allowed me to (re)set the root pw.

Answer (score 0):

Just spent forever on this.. so many solutions did not work. Finally this worked for me.

Restart MySQL with `skip-grant-tables`, which bypasses security, and now you can log in and run:

```
USE mysql;
CHECK TABLE user;
REPAIR TABLE user;
```

Apparently I had corrupted users or something.. and this resolved it. After this, I found I no longer had a root user. So I had to add with the following command (being in with `skip-grant-tables`):

```
INSERT INTO mysql.user 
SET user = 'root', 
host = 'localhost', 
password = Password('yournewrootpw'), 
Select_priv = 'Y',
Insert_priv = 'Y',
Update_priv = 'Y',
Delete_priv = 'Y',
Create_priv = 'Y',
Drop_priv = 'Y',
Reload_priv = 'Y',
Shutdown_priv = 'Y',
Process_priv = 'Y',
File_priv = 'Y',
Grant_priv = 'Y',
References_priv = 'Y',
Index_priv = 'Y',
Alter_priv = 'Y',
Show_db_priv = 'Y',
Super_priv = 'Y',
Create_tmp_table_priv = 'Y',
Lock_tables_priv = 'Y',
Execute_priv = 'Y',
Repl_slave_priv = 'Y',
Repl_client_priv = 'Y',
Create_view_priv = 'Y',
Show_view_priv = 'Y',
Create_routine_priv = 'Y',
Alter_routine_priv = 'Y',
Create_user_priv = 'Y',
Event_priv = 'Y',
Trigger_priv = 'Y',
Create_tablespace_priv = 'Y';
```

Hopefully this saves someone else a bunch of time..