# WAMP Re-install causes error: Could not execute... The service has not been started

Tags: apache, wamp

Full error reads:

```
Could not execute menu item (internal error)
[Exception] Could not perform service action:
The service has not been started
```

After doing a bit of googling, this problem should be caused by another service/process that's using the port I'm trying to use (80). When I go to `Wamp->Apache->Services->Test port 80`, it appears some OTHER apache program is using that port. I'm not sure where it is or how it got there, but I can't find it installed anywhere.

Additionally, attempts to stop the Apache service that's taking up the port gives me another error:

```
The operation could not be completed.
Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Skype running, kill all Skype processes.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but not with Skype. My solution is to click 'Stop All Services' from the Wamp Menu, then manually kill the httpd.exe processes from Task Manager. (It might have 2 httpd.exe  running, kill all)

Then 'Start All Services' from the Wamp menu, and it's working again.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first time when I got this error

```
"Could not execute menu item (internal error)
[Exception] Could not perform service action:
The service has not been started"
```

I did the following

- I went inside the Wamp->Apache->http config
- changed the port to 8080 and saved  (Listen xx.xx.xx.xx:8080
                           Listen 8080)
- clicked the wamp icon and clicked 'Restart all services'
- clicked the wapm icon and 'put online'

this worked for me